# How to get the result into a variable?

Tags: php, variables, time, echo

Might be a kinda noob question.

But I currently have this code:

```
<?php
$seconds = 1;
$h = (int)($seconds / 3600);
$m = (int)(($seconds - $h*3600) / 60);
$s = (int)($seconds - $h*3600 - $m*60);
if ($h > 1)
    echo "$h hours ago";
else if ($m > 1)
    echo "$m minutes ago";
else if ($s > 20)
    echo "$s seconds ago";
else echo "a moment ago";
$ThisTime = result
?>
```

Reminder: seconds is a variable that normally gets defined by an other variable.

What I want is:
for instance with "seconds = 1", the output is: "a moment ago". But i want that echo to be 
$ThisTime, how can i do this.

Reminder 2: If the input is 400000, the output is: 111 hours ago. So it defines by multiple variables.

Stupid me:

```
<?php
$seconds = 1;
$h = (int)($seconds / 3600);
$m = (int)(($seconds - $h*3600) / 60);
$s = (int)($seconds - $h*3600 - $m*60);
if ($h > 1)
    $Thistime = "$h hours ago";
else if ($m > 1)
    $Thistime = "$m minutes ago";
else if ($s > 20)
    $Thistime = "$s seconds ago";
else $Thistime = "a moment ago";
?>
```

**EDIT :::::**
Ok, i found another problem.

The time is specified in a database.
And it displays there like this: "1407922779"
How can I cahnge this value to be x minutes ago?
Because if i enter that, it says like 30 years ago (something like that).
While it just has been made.

Comment: Replace your `echo`s with `$ThisTime = `?

Comment: indeed, as George said, replace all your `echo` with `$ThisTime =`. Moreover, you may also define `$ThisTime` before the if.. Sometimes compilers may throw a notice. And, of course, remove `$ThisTime = result` and replace it with `echo $ThisTime;`, if you want to to print the output.

Comment: Should have thought about that xD

Comment: what should be your output for `1hr 1min 10sec`? `a moment ago`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$seconds = 1;
$h = (int)($seconds / 3600);
$m = (int)(($seconds - $h*3600) / 60);
$s = (int)($seconds - $h*3600 - $m*60);
if ($h > 1) {
    $result = "$h hours ago";
} elseif ($m > 1) {
    $result = "$m minutes ago";
} elseif ($s > 20) {
    $result = "$s seconds ago";
} else {
    $result = "a moment ago";
}
$ThisTime = $result;
?>
```